# How to resolve the Null Issue when using "revalue" from plyr package

Tags: r, r-markdown, plyr

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMnC3.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMnC3.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMnC3.png): **strong text**https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oVDk.png

I'm trying to create a new variable JobLevelPos with revaluing the values of 1,2,3,4,5 to  Entry, Middle ,senior top and Executive.

Also added the Code.

I'm getting levels output as a NULL.

```
library(plyr)
attr$JobLevelPos <- revalue(attr$JobLevelCat, c("1" = "Entry", 
                                                "2" = "Middle", 
                                                "3" = "Senior", 
                                                "4" = "Top", 
                                                "5" = "Executive"))
as.factor(attr$JobLevelPos)
levels(attr$JobLevelPos)
```

Comment: I should take a look at the data, but a problem could be that your values are numeric in your dataset and characters in your named vector.

Comment: HI Josep I have added the attachment of the dataset

Comment: Hi again! Instead of an image, it will be easier to help you if you provided a reproducible dataset. You may use `dput(head(atrr))` and copy&paste the result in your question. On the other hand, on the image you provided, I couldn't see the column JobLevelCat

Answer (score 1):

If the values in the original vector are 'Entry', 'Middle', the name value should be reversed i.e.

```
attr$JobLevelPos <- revalue(attr$JobLevelCat, c( "Entry" = "1", 
                                                "Middle" = "2", 
                                                "Senior" = "3", 
                                                "Top" = "4", 
                                                "Executive" = "5"))
```

It is mentioned in the help page of `?revalue`

> revalue(x, replace = NULL, warn_missing = TRUE)

where

> replace - named character vector, with **new values as values**, and **old values as names**.

We construct the named vector with `c(oldvalue = newvalue)`

-reproducible example

```
>  v1 <- c("Entry", "Middle", "Senior", "Entry")
> plyr::revalue(v1, c("1" = "Entry"))
The following `from` values were not present in `x`: 1
> plyr::revalue(v1, c("Entry" = "1"))
[1] "1"      "Middle" "Senior" "1"
```